# how to send one component form input data to my parent component to submit the form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have three child component with form in each and one parent component, i want to inject all three child component forms to my parent component and do a submit.My goal is to display all three form data in json format.
Child 1:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { PropTypes } from 'react'

class Input extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      id: '',
      inputType: '' ,
      inputFilePath: '',
      inputSchemaFilePath: '' ,
      streamName: '',
      processor: '',
      unit: ''
    }
    this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this)
    //this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this)
}  

handleInputChange = e => {
    console.log(e.target.value);
    //this.setState({[e.target.name] : e.target.value});
    this.setState({
      id: e.target.value,
      inputType: e.target.value,
      inputFilePath: e.target.value,
      streamName: e.target.value,
      processor: e.target.value,
      unit: e.target.value
    });
   
  };

  render() {
  
    return (
      <form>
      <div>
   
      <h2>Input:</h2>
        <ul>
            <li><label> Id : </label><input type="text" size="100" name="id" value={this.state.id} onChange={this.handleInputChange} /></li>
            <li><label> InputType : </label><input type="text" size="100" name="inputType" value={this.state.inputType} onChange={this.handleInputChange} /></li>
            <li><label> InputFilePath : </label><input type="text" size="100" name="inputFilePath" value={this.state.inputFilePath} onChange={this.handleInputChange}/></li>
            <li><label> InputSchemaFilePath : </label><input type="text" size="100" name="inputSchemaFilePath" value={this.state.inputSchemaFilePath} onChange={this.handleInputChange}/></li>
            <li><label> StreamName : </label><input type="text" size="100" name="streamName" value={this.state.streamName} onChange={this.handleInputChange}/> </li>
            <li><label> Processor : </label><input type="text" size="100" name="processor" value={this.state.processor} onChange={this.handleInputChange} /></li>
            <li><label> Unit : </label><input type="text" size="100" name="unit" value={this.state.unit} onChange={this.handleInputChange} /></li>
          <button> <span>+</span></button>
          <button> <span>-</span></button>
        </ul>
      </div>
      </form>
    );
  }
}
export default Input
```

Child 2

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { PropTypes } from 'react'

class Output extends Component {

   constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      id: '',
      outputType: '' ,
      saveMode: '',
      outputFilePath: '' ,
      outputSchemaFilePath: '',
      dependentIds: '',
      outputPartitionKeys: '',
      processor: ''
    }
    this.handleOutputChange = this.handleOutputChange.bind(this)
    //this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleOutputChange = e => {
    console.log(e.target.value);
    this.setState({
      id: e.target.value,
      outputType: e.target.value,
      saveMode: e.target.value,
      outputFilePath: e.target.value,
      outputSchemaFilePath: e.target.value,
      dependentIds: e.target.value,
      processor: e.target.value
    });
  };
  render() {

    return (
      <form>
      <div>
       <h1>Output:</h1>
        <ul>
            <li><label> Id : </label><input type="text" size="100" name="id" value={this.state.id} onChange={this.handleChange} /></li>
            <li><label> OutputType : </label><input type="text" size="100" name="outputType" value={this.state.outputType}  onChange={this.handleChange}/></li>
            <li><label> SaveMode : </label><input type="text" size="100" name="saveMode" value={this.state.saveMode} onChange={this.handleChange} /></li>
            <li><label> OutputFilePath : </label><input type="text" size="100" name="outputFilePath" value={this.state.outputFilePath} onChange={this.handleChange} /></li>
            <li><label> OutputSchemaFilePath : </label><input type="text" size="100" name="outputSchemaFilePath" value={this.state.outputSchemaFilePath} onChange={this.handleChange} /> </li>
            <li><label> DependentIds : </label><input type="text" size="100" name="dependentIds" value={this.state.dependentIds} onChange={this.handleChange} /></li>
            <li><label> OutputPartitionKeys : </label><input type="text" size="100" name="outputPartitionKeys" value={this.state.outputPartitionKeys} onChange={this.handleChange} /></li>
            <li><label> Processor : </label><input type="text" size="100" name="processor"  value={this.state.processor} onChange={this.handleChange}/></li>
            <button> <span>+</span></button>
            <button> <span>-</span></button> 
          </ul>    
        </div>
        </form>
    );
  }
}

export default Output
```

---

similarly there is one more component .
Parent Component :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import Input from './input';
import Transformation from './transformation';
import Output from './output';
import JSONPretty from 'react-json-pretty';
import { PropTypes } from 'react'

class Parent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
        };
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
        
      }

  handleSubmit(values) { 
    console.log(values)
   

    this.setState({ values })
    //code
  } 

  render() {
     return (
      <div class="ot">
      <h1>Header</h1>
        <b>Please fill all the required fields marked with <span class="req">*</span></b>
        <br/>
            
              <h2><Input /></h2>
              <h2><Transformation /></h2>
              <h2><Output /></h2>
              <button onClick={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}>Show JSL</button>
          <JSONPretty id="json-pretty" data={this.data}></JSONPretty>

            </div>
      
        );
    }
}export default Parent
```

Can anyone suggest what code should go to in parent component ??

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to retrieve the input data from Child1 and Child2 in Parent component you will have to manage their state in the Parent component. You can then pass it down as Props to Child1 and 2

This will allow you to validate your Child's logic inside `handleSubmit(values) {...}`  in the Parent component

Comment: can u  tell me what change and where exactly

Comment: move Child1 and Child2 state in the parent component. So 

`this.state = {
      id: '',
      outputType: '' ,
      saveMode: '',
      outputFilePath: '' ,
      outputSchemaFilePath: '',
      dependentIds: '',
      outputPartitionKeys: '',
      processor: ''
    }`

and 

`this.state = {
      id: '',
      inputType: '' ,
      inputFilePath: '',
      inputSchemaFilePath: '' ,
      streamName: '',
      processor: '',
      unit: ''
    }`
in parent and then pass it down as props : 
  `<h2><Input inputType={this.state.inputType}......../></h2>`

Comment: this is not helping because i need to bind the form inputs , i should not use same state in parent component for all child component